# FCPX: change export resolution and remove black bars

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, handbrake

I have a set of Super 8 movies, digitized to Full HD MP4. This results in black bars left and right. I've imported the movies into Final Cut Pro x 10.4, with those bars. After doing some editing, I prefer to export them without the bars to a 1440x1080 resolution. I can create a project with that resolution. I can crop the clips to that resolution, but if I export it, I get 1920x1080. I don't know what I doing wrong.

Handbrake removes these bars automatically, but exports to 30fps while the movies are 24fps. And I prefer to export directly from FCP.

**How can I export movies without the black bars?**

Answer (score 1):

This article should help 
[custom resolution and frame rate in FCPX](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/custom-resolution-frame-rates-fcpx/)

Comment: Hi German Dude, what will happen to your answer if the link breaks, maybe you could include a summary ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi This article might help as well, sending direct from FCPX to Handbrake
[FCPX to Handbrake](http://tpayton.com/handbrake-and-fcpx/?fbclid=IwAR2R6DuU0hjV2xb42dW4Bi4ypMO00gJR4-xmkI_DnGBF3i6aZUFmNV8JzoY)

Comment: Thanks for that link. As I see it, the best option is to export to mov in FCP, then let Handbrake strip the bars and convert to mp4. The automator takes away one step.

Comment: Hi Adam, what will happen to your answer if the link breaks, maybe you could include a summary ?